# How to reverse boxes in a row below row with two boxes using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to make a different boxes in a row: one - 33% width, second - 66% width. In a row below this I want to make same sized boxes but in reverse position like below on the picture:

[image]

Can't use every time new row with row-reverse style because client wants edit boxes in Wordpress using ACF Repeater, so it should be done only by CSS.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.box:nth-child(even) {
  flex: 0 0 66.666%;
  max-width: 66.666%;
}
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
}

.box__item {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
<div class='box__item'> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use row-reverse?

Comment: check the order property for flexbox

Comment: Can't use row-reverse cause boxes should be in one row not boxes in multiple rows.
Can't use order because number of boxes can be changed.

Comment: the number of box for every row remains 2?

Comment: Yes, always will be 2.

Comment: Why does it have to be flexbox and not, say, grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `nth-child()`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n),
.box:nth-child(4n-3){
  flex: 0 0 66.666%;
  max-width: 66.666%;
}

.box:nth-child(4n-1),
.box:nth-child(4n-2){
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
}

.box__item {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
    <div class='box__item'> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```